# display 2 different select queries with different columns in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
select u_id AS user1 from user where u_id = 2;
select u.u_id AS user2 from user u INNER JOIN trip t ON u.u_id = t.u_id WHERE t.u_id2 = 2;
```

How can i display both user1 and user2 in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to join to the users table twice, the second time via `trip.u_id2`:

```
SELECT u.u_id AS user1, u2.u_id as user2
FROM user u
   INNER JOIN trip t ON u.u_id = t.u_id 
   INNER JOIN user u2 ON t.u_id2 = u2.u_id
WHERE t.u_id2 = 2;
```

Just note that I've adjusted the aliasing to match the suffixes. If `t.u_id2` or `t.u_id` are nullable, then you should replace with a LEFT join.

**Re : Is this optimal**

Since your original query just references the User Ids, then there is no need to join to the user table at all:

```
SELECT t.u_id AS user1, t.u_id2 as user2
FROM trip t
WHERE t.u_id2 = 2;
```

But obviously now you are limited to just the FOREIGN key for the user, which might not be useful to an end user.

Comment: is this the optimize way? will joining the same table twice reduce the performance?

Comment: Well, since you are currently just selecting the user_id keys, there isn't really a need to join to user at all. But then you obviously won't have access to other `user` table columns, e.g. names etc. But in general, if you do need other columns from table user, then two joins will be needed. Provided that the keys are indexed (or made into primary keys) and the foreign keys are indexed, you shouldn't have any performance issues.

Comment: Does stored procedure allow me to select 2 different queries without joining? #justasking

Comment: Yes that is also possible, but unlikely to be more performant than a two column select. From the docs "Multiple SELECT statements generate multiple result sets, so the client must use a MySQL client library that supports multiple result sets." and "The client should also specify the CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS option" [from here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines-syntax.html)